# Google Sheets: show different rows for specific users

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Is there a way, to make certain rows in Google Spreadsheets, be editable and accessible to a certain user, while not be accessible to another user?**

I have a spreadsheet which 70 or so people need to access and input their data into the rows that are allocated to them. Previously, I just protected each row so that they couldn't edit anyone else's rows but ideally I would also like to hide everyone else's rows. Example spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BBe_j1UuexPg49TlALL9k2n12ICz85YE5fYtU294it4/edit?usp=sharing).

At the moment, I've tried to use a script to hide and show certain rows depending on the email address of the person accessing the spreadsheet. However, this affects the view of everyone looking at the spreadsheet currently. My code is:

```
    function onOpen(e){
        var email = (Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail());
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

        switch (email){
             case 'user1@email.com':
             sheet.hideRows(7, sheet.getMaxRows()-6);
             break;
        case 'user2@email.com':
             sheet.hideRows(2, 5);
             sheet.showRows(7, 5);
             sheet.hideRows(12, sheet.getMaxRows()-11);
             break;
        case 'user3@email.com':
             sheet.hideRows(2, 10);
             sheet.showRows(12, 5);
             sheet.hideRows(17, sheet.getMaxRows()-16);
             break;
```

...etc.

My question is: is there a way to make these views viewer-specific rather than global? Or am I doomed to go through each row and just use the protection feature every time I need to generate this spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a form attached to the sheet? It will keep users from overwriting other responses, hide other responses.

Comment: Unfortunately, the data on this spreadsheet will change often as plans get refined. I know you can edit form responses, but they will need to see the latest changes. We also use the form as a dialogue (via comments) between the team to save on hundreds of emails being passed around.